# KingSpec SSD partitioning -- start partition from sector 63 or 64?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I've recently bought a KSD-PA25.6-064MS, and it came pre-formatted, with the partition starting at sector 63.

I know this isn't typical for SSDs and can result in excessive write amplification. However, since this is what the manufacturer did, it *might* be specifically made for this particular layout.

[The specs at the manufacturer's site](http://www.kingspec.com/en/product_xx157.html) do not tell anything about erase blocks or the like. Likewise, I couldn't yet contact the manufacturer directly - no channel specified on their site seems to work.

Did anyone do performance tests or something to find out the internal parameters and specifically the aforementioned matter?

I'm not interested in [general information about SSD structure](http://www.flashmemorysummit.com/English/Collaterals/Proceedings/2012/20120821_TB11_Sykes.pdf). I'm specifically interested in KingSpec drives (the closer to my model, the better) - if they are special or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately failed to get *any* answer from the manufacturer, even when I CC'd their Oversea Sales Manager (the only contact channel at their site that proved to work) and he forwarded my message to an appropriate department with a request for them to respond to it.

According to [Determining internal sector size for SSD for possible partition alignment - PC Review newsgroups](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/determining-internal-sector-size-for-ssd-for-possible-partitionalignment.4034413/), KingSpec drives use stock 3rd party flash chips (as expected for a lower price segment product) - so the chances of any unusual internals are very slim.

[According to](https://superuser.com/questions/728858/how-to-determine-ssds-nand-erase-block-size/992088) `flashbench` output:

```
$ flashbench -a /dev/sda -b 1024
align 536870912 pre 547Вµs  on 702Вµs   post 528Вµs diff 164Вµs
align 268435456 pre 540Вµs  on 700Вµs   post 544Вµs diff 158Вµs
align 134217728 pre 565Вµs  on 717Вµs   post 531Вµs diff 168Вµs
align 67108864  pre 571Вµs  on 727Вµs   post 547Вµs diff 168Вµs
align 33554432  pre 554Вµs  on 732Вµs   post 554Вµs diff 178Вµs
align 16777216  pre 568Вµs  on 664Вµs   post 551Вµs diff 104Вµs
align 8388608   pre 575Вµs  on 644Вµs   post 590Вµs diff 61.2Вµs
align 4194304   pre 576Вµs  on 644Вµs   post 590Вµs diff 60.9Вµs
align 2097152   pre 576Вµs  on 645Вµs   post 591Вµs diff 61.5Вµs
align 1048576   pre 577Вµs  on 646Вµs   post 591Вµs diff 61.8Вµs
align 524288    pre 576Вµs  on 646Вµs   post 593Вµs diff 61.5Вµs
align 262144    pre 575Вµs  on 646Вµs   post 590Вµs diff 62.8Вµs
align 131072    pre 583Вµs  on 649Вµs   post 574Вµs diff 70.3Вµs
align 65536 pre 585Вµs  on 653Вµs   post 582Вµs diff 70Вµs
align 32768 pre 586Вµs  on 652Вµs   post 580Вµs diff 68.7Вµs
align 16384 pre 584Вµs  on 624Вµs   post 586Вµs diff 39.4Вµs
align 8192  pre 586Вµs  on 605Вµs   post 587Вµs diff 19Вµs
align 4096  pre 585Вµs  on 605Вµs   post 586Вµs diff 19.4Вµs
align 2048  pre 584Вµs  on 584Вµs   post 585Вµs diff 379ns
```

my drive uses 16K sectors and 16M erase blocks.

Now, let's see the timings for the partition:

```
$ flashbench -a /dev/sda1 -b 1024
align 536870912 pre 690Вµs  on 671Вµs   post 722Вµs diff -35600n
align 268435456 pre 707Вµs  on 683Вµs   post 734Вµs diff -37774n
align 134217728 pre 691Вµs  on 672Вµs   post 724Вµs diff -36217n
align 67108864  pre 711Вµs  on 688Вµs   post 741Вµs diff -37954n
align 33554432  pre 717Вµs  on 694Вµs   post 746Вµs diff -37195n
align 16777216  pre 714Вµs  on 692Вµs   post 744Вµs diff -36476n
align 8388608   pre 759Вµs  on 736Вµs   post 786Вµs diff -36996n
align 4194304   pre 757Вµs  on 732Вµs   post 782Вµs diff -37075n
align 2097152   pre 758Вµs  on 733Вµs   post 783Вµs diff -38152n
align 1048576   pre 757Вµs  on 735Вµs   post 788Вµs diff -37275n
align 524288    pre 759Вµs  on 736Вµs   post 786Вµs diff -36078n
align 262144    pre 754Вµs  on 733Вµs   post 789Вµs diff -38073n
align 131072    pre 738Вµs  on 718Вµs   post 766Вµs diff -33265n
align 65536 pre 747Вµs  on 728Вµs   post 773Вµs diff -32086n
align 32768 pre 745Вµs  on 725Вµs   post 776Вµs diff -35799n
```

WTF? No patterns and *negative* diffs? Indeed, this suggests that reads are not aligned to SSD blocks.

In verity, if I change the partition start to sector 64, the output changes to a more expected:

```
$ flashbench -a /dev/sda1 -b 1024
align 536870912 pre 531Вµs  on 600Вµs   post 530Вµs diff 69.3Вµs
align 268435456 pre 543Вµs  on 611Вµs   post 542Вµs diff 68.4Вµs
align 134217728 pre 531Вµs  on 600Вµs   post 531Вµs diff 68.9Вµs
align 67108864  pre 548Вµs  on 618Вµs   post 548Вµs diff 69.8Вµs
align 33554432  pre 555Вµs  on 624Вµs   post 553Вµs diff 70.4Вµs
align 16777216  pre 552Вµs  on 622Вµs   post 552Вµs diff 69.9Вµs
align 8388608   pre 594Вµs  on 664Вµs   post 592Вµs diff 71.1Вµs
align 4194304   pre 593Вµs  on 660Вµs   post 590Вµs diff 68.7Вµs
align 2097152   pre 590Вµs  on 660Вµs   post 593Вµs diff 69.1Вµs
align 1048576   pre 593Вµs  on 665Вµs   post 595Вµs diff 71.6Вµs
align 524288    pre 594Вµs  on 663Вµs   post 591Вµs diff 70.1Вµs
align 262144    pre 593Вµs  on 664Вµs   post 594Вµs diff 70.5Вµs
align 131072    pre 578Вµs  on 643Вµs   post 577Вµs diff 65.4Вµs
align 65536 pre 583Вµs  on 650Вµs   post 577Вµs diff 70Вµs
align 32768 pre 583Вµs  on 654Вµs   post 587Вµs diff 68.8Вµs
align 16384 pre 581Вµs  on 623Вµs   post 584Вµs diff 40.4Вµs
align 8192  pre 583Вµs  on 601Вµs   post 582Вµs diff 17.9Вµs
align 4096  pre 582Вµs  on 601Вµs   post 583Вµs diff 19Вµs
align 2048  pre 581Вµs  on 581Вµs   post 581Вµs diff -479ns
```