# External SSD formating parameters, usage and monitoring on Windows 10

Tags: ssd, ntfs, formatting, samsung-ssd

I have a brand new Samsung T5 1Tb SSD, that I will use for back-up of files on my laptops, as well as main drive for photos and music collection. Before starting to use it, I did some searching/reading (it's my first external SSD), and I now have more questions than answers.

### File system

Not really a question; after some reading I convinced myself that NTFS should be better than exFAT (out-of-the-box FS), so I will reformat the drive.

### Alignment

This was something completely new for me. I understood that it is *important* but as I will create only a single partition, Windows 10 should take care of the necessary offset and that this is correctly applied ("offset divided by 4096 should be integer number").

### Erase blocks

So I did the reading ([great article from Extremetech](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/210492-extremetech-explains-how-do-ssds-work)), understand the importance of Erase blocks and Page sizes, but I am now wondering whether I *practically* have to take this into account when formatting my drive (cluster size)?

A [SU article](https://superuser.com/questions/1243559/is-partition-alignment-to-ssd-erase-block-size-pointless) dealing with the same question, but the answer is not really clear to me.

### NTFS Parameters

I know that many articles exist about deciding cluster size for HDD, and I understand the trade-offs between higher speed but more "lost" space by increasing the cluster size, but I would like to revisit the question specifically for SSD and 2021 context:

- Should the fact it is a SSD influence the cluster size?
- Does the fact that user files nowadays are so much larger than even a decade ago (multimedia files, but also other user files, like doc/ppt/xls) makes it better to ignore the recommended 4K and go for larger cluster size?
- As a side question, I do not understand why [Microsoft's default/recommended cluster size](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat-9772e6f1-e31a-00d7-e18f-73169155af95) for NTFS is 4K for drives up to 16Tb, but is already 32K for exFAT for drives as small as 256Mb.
- Should cluster size be influenced by the aforementioned SSD "erase block size", or has one nothing to do with the other ? And if so, where to find this information for my drive (this is apparently a closely guarded *secret*)?

[This article of Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/7531/would-ssd-drives-benefit-from-a-non-default-allocation-unit-size) asks a similar question, but it references an article that is not online anymore and does not give a clear answer.

### Usage

I read something about enabling TRIM in Windows 10, but not sure whether his is only applicable for internal OS drives, or also for external drives? And if so, is this something I have to enable manually, or run occasionally (for wear leveling)?

### Monitoring

Given it is an external SSD, is it recommended to monitor the health, or is this only relevant for internal SSDs that are used continuously by the OS and applications ?
The fact that Samsung's own Magician software does only work with internal SSDs, and the software for the T5 is absolutely minimal (only for encryption and firmware updates?), makes me think it is not needed, but an expert opinion would be appreciated.

Comment: SSD's don't have an offset

Comment: I have a 2 TB Samsung drive on my desktop for this. Install it, use it, set Trim to be Automatic (Admin Tools, Optimize), and install Samsung Magician to run in the System tray to monitor health.

Comment: @John Thanks, but you have an internal drive? My question concerns an external SSD. I installed Samsung Magician, but this doesn't recognize the drive; the manual only lists internal SSDs.

Comment: My two Samsung SSDs are both internal - yes.

Comment: I myself disagree with "monitoring".. all I need is another crap program running in my systray.  Checking the status of the drive periodically is the only way to go IMHO.  Others will disagree.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks. What do you use to "check periodically"?

Comment: In some cases, I run the thing that would otherwise run  in my systray.. then I kill it.